# open file using vscode from virtual machine

Tags: vscode-debugger, vscode-remote

I am using mac terminal to ssh to a virtual machine.
I am more comfortable using through terminal so what configurations can I make to open my files using vs code from that remote machine.

eg ssh user@x.x.x.x has file hello.txt and I want to open it from my terminal code hello.txt

Also, I dont want to open it using vscode app's terminal as navigation is not smooth.

Comment: have you considered using ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh or Kelvin.vscode-sshfs ?